# Navigatable link to Dropbox unshared file/folder

Tags: url, hyperlink, dropbox-api

Is there any way to programmatically get/generate navigatable link to Dropbox file/folder which is not shared so user will first be asked to login and then navigate to the file/folder e.g. in browser?
I see the links in web-interface like `https://www.dropbox.com/pri/get/Get%20Started%20with%20Dropbox.pdf?_subject_uid=bla-bla-bla` but

1. how to programmatically get/generate correct `_subject_uid`
2. if the first part of the URL is stable or there is no such guarantee

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, Dropbox doesn't offer an official/documented interface for linking to private items like this. We'll consider this a feature request though.